# Hiding content after certain number of characters breaking on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I've added this css to a file in order to cut off content at the first line and generate and ending ellipses:

```
#description{
overflow: hidden;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

I checked this with a description on Chrome and it worked perfectly by taking multiple lines of text with several paragraph and anchor tags, and wrapping after the first line then appending an ellipses.

However, On safari it seems to shove all of the content into the small div. It does show the ellipses after the first line but it also crowds all other text and content into an illegible block rather than actually hiding it.

I'm not sure what to do here or what's actually causing the issue to where it will work on  Chrome but not safari.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to show only the first line, (as I can understand from *-webkit-line-clamp: 1;*) then you can use the following:

```css
#description{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="description">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris convallis nisl felis, sit amet bibendum leo fermentum et. Nulla ut ornare enim, eu tristique tellus. Nulla facilisi. Nunc imperdiet ante id tristique fringilla. Mauris magna leo, tempor congue magna at, rhoncus vestibulum magna. Donec quis vestibulum massa. Vivamus placerat consectetur efficitur. Aenean lacinia malesuada neque nec venenatis. Donec sagittis, metus ut commodo aliquet, odio magna gravida justo, vitae laoreet est est id lectus. Donec tincidunt porttitor mi, eget laoreet velit placerat ac. 
</div>
```

the above will also work in browsers, that they do not support the *-webkit* prefix, like Firefox